# Designing scalable graphics without using vectors

Tags: resize, android, iphone, games

I'm working on an mobile phone game, and don't have the luxury of being able to use vector graphics. I'd like the game to be playable on a wide range of devices from 2560x1600 tablets to 320x240 phones. Ideally I want a single set of graphical assets for all resolutions.

Vector data is not supported on a wide range of mobile devices, that's why I'm limited.

As a general rule, I'll be creating everything for a high end device and be scaling down when the game loads which gives me basic linear filtering.

Are there any particular guidelines I should follow when creating scalable graphics? Fonts are a particular headache. I've noticed that smoother fonts with soft edges seem to scale a better than sharp fonts. These are the kinds of tips that I'm after.

Comment: I'm a complete newb to design but surely you create them exactly the same way: with vectors. You just export them as .png or whatever at each resolution instead of using an svg, no?

Comment: @OGHaza I don't know what the resolution will be, there are probably 30-40 different phone resolutions now, and I'm not manually creating graphics for all of those. The scaling will happen on the phone once the game knows the resolution.

Comment: Riiiiight, sorry misunderstood!

Comment: You would still be better of doing it with vectors and then take a really high res version you resample down. Granted now your vector drawings could have lots of free artistry in the mix. Fonts always as hinted vectors please.

Comment: This could be a huge mistake. Have you checked what happens to a raster image when you simply "squish" it down 200, 300, or 400%? Details can plug and vanish. This is why vector data is often preferred.

Comment: @Scott vector data is not easily supported on all devices, that's the issue. The question is how to create graphics that scale well. For example, I've found that bitmap fonts with soft edges scale a lot better than sharper fonts. These are the kinds of tips I'm looking for.

Comment: That information would be helpful in the question, Will.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, question updated to make the limitations more clear.

Comment: FWIW, I believe webkit browsers support SVG just fine...which would encompass a large swath of mobile devices (namely iOS and Android)

Answer (score 2):

I am skeptical about the idea that "vectors aren't supported." I am certain that libraries exist for all mobile platforms: vectors are only ever viewed as raster images.

{**edit for clarity**:}
While the "mipmap" discussion below refers to 3d rendering, the mipmaps themselves are "raster" textures to be applied during rendering. There is no reason one cannot use the mipmap concept as assets in a pixel-based 2d render without a 3d pipeline...
{**end edit**}

In any event, the most common alternative is a mipmap, either calculated on the fly (cpu intensive, less control), or pre-rendered and stored (more storage). Mipmaps are usually used for 3d level of detail (LOD) where the best assets are only required for things closest to the viewport.

If you have a pre-rendered graphic(s) with multiple sizes in it, you can choose the proper asset to use based upon the viewport size. This also allows for a low/med/high user preference if they encounter unsuitable performance. Additionally, you can package the assets by size and perhaps leave out the highest pixel dimension set for devices that are storage limited.

Because scaling always involves quality loss, it is probably beneficial to pre-render the assets so that you can fix them up for quality.

( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap )

> In 3D computer graphics, mipmaps (also MIP maps) are pre-calculated,
>   optimized collections of images that accompany a main texture,
>   intended to increase rendering speed and reduce aliasing artifacts.

"aliasing artifacts" = Scott's "huge mistake" comment.

---

- 2d mipmaps (all GPU has this) = hardware accelerated sparse pixel quadtree
- 3d mipmaps (post-2020 generation GPU) = hardware accelerated sparse voxel octree

Comment: Note that I get that you want a single set, but this is *the* reason for the supremacy of vector and 3d modeling in gaming and graphics.

Comment: If you look at, for example, the Candy Crush Saga installer, you'll see they use bitmaps, spritesheets and bitmap fonts. They've put a lot of time, money and effort into producing a game that can be played on almost any and every device. If the worlds biggest grossing company in the mobile games market takes that route then I feel I should follow their lead.

Comment: @WillCalderwood following the lead of 'biggest grossing' software companies is not any sort of guarantee for building quality solutions. (See also: Microsoft, IBM, etc.)

Comment: But, all that said, it sounds like you're determined to not use scalable files, so I would ask what your question is, then? It sounds like you've already decided to use raster image sprites.

Comment: @DA01 My question is how to create raster graphics that scale well, for example, fonts with soft edges. I was wondering if anyone else had some tips.

Comment: @WillCalderwood ah! I see. Raster images, alas, just don't scale well to begin with. I think the one bit of advice would be to just be sure to not have so much detail in them that it disappears when you scale down. (That said, fonts should likely be left as text within the app rather than rendered as images)

Comment: @DA01 Unfortunately, when rendering through the GPU you don't have the luxury of rending fonts as anything other than images.

Comment: @WillCalderwood: regarding the installer, is it a single universal installer for all devices, or have they done what I suggest and package the assets based upon pixel size/target viewport size? They may *not* be making "scalable" graphics, but targeting viewport sizes and living with some minimal scaling variance. .8x-1.2x is often undetectable, but 3x scaling gets blurry, pixelated, lines drop out etc.. A mipmap is/can be constructed as a sprite sheet of one non-animated sprite, and it can be handled in a very similar way..

Comment: @WillCalderwood: it occurs to me from your first comment I wasn't as clear as I could be. I was suggesting the mipmap concept for 2d raster art, not a 3d renderer.

Comment: @WillCalderwood what platform are you building your game on? You've mention HTML5 and canvas so I assume it's perhaps something akin to PhoneGap? If so, it's rather trivial to load fonts into your app.

Comment: @horatio Good point about different installers for different devices. I'll check the apks on a few of my phones.

Comment: @DA01 I'm creating it using libgdx, which is basically an OpenGL wrapper that builds for a range of devices. Everything goes through the GPU and ttf fonts don't go through a GPU. I can create fonts when the game runs, but it's very slow and the quality isn't great. I moved away from HTML5 as Javascript is horrible and it wasn't fast enough. I was only getting 6fps on an old Android phone compared to an easy 60fps with native code.

Comment: "Javascript is horrible" = oh, I see. In terms of speed. Yes, I it's not great for everything (though I am surprised every day how much more we can do with it).

Comment: So, this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322995/is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-vector-graphics-into-libgdx-development Looks like that platform doesn't do vector images well yet. So, you may be stuck with the rasters.

Comment: @DA01 It sounds like SVG has similar problems to the HTML5 canvas, in that everyone implements it slightly differently - and there are a lot of browsers out there. With regards to Javascript, you can do an amazing amount with it - and speed it a lot better than it was a few years ago. But maintenance of large projects is a headache. Also, there are a few ok development environments now - but none that seem to work amazingly well.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to focus on iOS mainly, but mobile safari has supported SVG for a while now. Apparently Android's browser on Honeycomb and up also supports SVG. I tend to only use SVG for most of my icons in mobile iOS work.

The alternative is to use raster, of course. If you want to use only one image for all devices, then you need to make a really large image, as you can scale down easily, but not up (and have it look good).

UPDATE:

If your question is

> are there scalable image formats that aren't vector?

Then the answer is no, not really. If it's not vector (we'll lump 3D modeling into that) then it's raster. Raster images have a finite number of pixels so can only be scaled up to that point. You can scale down from that with some success, but not usually up very much before it starts looking poor.

Comment: Trying to get performance out of an HTML5 canvas is hit and miss + it involves working in Javascript, which is horrible :-) And people complain about mobile fragmentation, but when you multiply that by the range of possible browsers, what they support and don't support, and how they render what they do render... it's horrible. I took a brief trip down that route and decided it wasn't worth it.

Comment: I'm talking about SVG--not canvas.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I've not come across SVG. I'll take a look.

Comment: SVG = Scalable Vector Graphic. You can make them in Adobe Illustrator, though many prefer Inkscape (it's open source + natively handles SVG quite nicely). You can then use them just as you'd use a PNG or GIF, except that they are vector, so will scale up to any size you'd like.

Comment: Looks like over 20% of android phones are still on earlier versions than Honeycomb, so SVG isn't really an option. It also looks like it wouldn't be great for things like particle effects. While it's an option I might have a play with sometime, it doesn't look like it's a real option just yet. It also looks like some SVG implementations don't take advantage of the GPU yet + it's not what GPUs were designed for. I discovered graphics through the CPU destroys battery life.